# Removing Share Permissions with Powershell

Tags: powershell, ntfs

I'm trying to write a script to add/remove file share permissions depending on what the user wants to do. Below is a snippet from the overall code. The "Add" works just fine. But when I try to use the "Remove" function, nothing happens.

```
function ModifyPermissions{
$group = Read-Host 'Enter group/account'
$permSet = Read-Host 'Enter level of permissions'
$action = Read-Host 'Add or Remove?'

If($action = "Add")
{
$acl = Get-Acl $Path

$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($group, $permSet, "Allow")

$acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)

$acl | Set-Acl $Path
} 
Else{
$acl = Get-Acl $Path

$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule($group, $permSet, "Allow")

$acl.RemoveAccessRule($AccessRule)

$acl | Set-Acl $Path
}
}
```

Maybe I'm overlooking something very obvious, which would be nice, but I just can't figure out why it's not doing what it's supposed to.

Comment: Change `$action = "Add"` to `$action -eq "Add"` - `=` is only for assignment, and `if($action = "add")` will _always_ be true

Comment: Ah! I knew it was something simple I was missing. It's working now. Thank you!